# Aligning Data with two different TimeStamps

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the first two columns (TimeStamp and Data value) and I need to align it with the 3rd column Timestamp. If they align with the same date then the data value can be aligned with that, but if they are off the value can be dragged down to the next matching time stamp. The timestamps for column A are pretty random, but for column C they are 15 minute intervals. I basically want data in column B to transfer to column D and be drug down with the same number until next matching timestamp.

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8/4/21 0:00 | 84.1 | 8/4/21 0:00 | 84.1 |
| 8/4/21 0:30 | 84.9 | 8/4/21 0:15 | 84.1 |
| 8/4/21 0:45 | 85.7 | 8/4/21 0:30 | 84.9 |

Comment: Try to post an image or share a file that shows what your data set is like and what' youre trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

In `D1` use: `=INDEX($B$1:$B$3,MAX(($A$1:$A$3<=C1)*ROW($A$1:$A$3)))` I think this needs confirmed with `ctrl+shift-enter` and dragged down in excel versions prior to Office 365.